# Mysql Dump Empty File

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to follow the many guides online to create a script that makes a backup of SQL database, but unfortunately I find myself with an error in the SQL command because I go to create a file is where I say, and as I say, but it is completely empty ..!
The syntax that use is as follows:

```
exec('mysqldump –opt -user=' . $db_user . ' -password=' . $db_pass . ' --host=' . $db_host . ' ' . $db_nome . ' > ' . $db_filename);
```

and this:

```
exec('mysqldump --user=' . $db_user . ' --password=' . $db_pass . ' --host=' . $db_host . ' ' . $db_nome . ' > ' . $db_filename);
echo 'mysqldump –opt -user=' . $db_user . ' -password=' . $db_pass . ' --host=' . $db_host . ' ' . $db_nome . ' > ' . $db_filename;
```

You see mistakes?

Comment: I take it you meant to put `$db_nome` instead of `$db_name`?

Comment: You should either use the short form `-u`/`-p` or the long form `--user`/`--password` but not `-user`/`-password`, so your second example should work.

Comment: Is correct.. name in italian is nome

Comment: Do you get the same result when executing the command in the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify **full path** to mysqldump:

```
exec('/usr/bin/mysqldump –opt -user=' . $db_user . ' -password=' . $db_pass . ' --host=' . $db_host . ' ' . $db_nome . ' > ' . $db_filename);
```

Comment: instead of -user must be --user or you can use just -u